# Calculate the area of a polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to get the area of a polygon in my map. I looked for an example of `new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea`, but I can't make it work, and I don't know why.

```
function dibuV(area){
  var i;
  var a = new Array();
  for(i=0; i<area.length; i++){
    var uno = area[i].split(",");
    a[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(uno[0],uno[1]);
  }
  poligon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: a,
    strokeColor: "#22B14C",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#22B14C",  
    fillOpacity: 0.35  
  })  
  poligon.setMap(map);//until here is ok 
  var z = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(poligon.getPath());
  alert(z); //this is not working
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The error that your code is giving you: `google.maps.geometry is undefined`

From the [Google Maps v3 API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry), the geometry functions are part of a library that is not loaded by default:

> The concepts within this document refer to features only available
>   within the google.maps.geometry library. This library is not loaded by
>   default when you load the Maps Javascript API but must be explicitly
>   specified through use of a libraries bootstrap parameter.

In order to load and use the geometry funcitons within your page, you need to inform Google that you will be using the geometry library, by adding it to your initial Google API call by including `libraries=geometry`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
```

This will then load the geometry library and your `z` variable will contain an object.

Test page with working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize()
    {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
<script>
function test()
{
var arr = new Array()
arr.push('51.5001524,-0.1262362');
arr.push('52.5001524,-1.1262362');
arr.push('53.5001524,-2.1262362');
arr.push('54.5001524,-3.1262362');
dibuV(arr);
}
function dibuV(area)
{
var a = new Array();

for(var i=0; i<area.length; i++)
{
    var uno = area[i].split(",");
    a[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(uno[0],uno[1]);
}

poligon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: a,
    strokeColor: "#22B14C",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#22B14C",   
    fillOpacity: 0.35   
})  

poligon.setMap(map);//until here is ok 
var z = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(poligon.getPath());
alert(z); //this is not working
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="test();">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know he's getting that error, I wonder?  For my part, with the drawing library already loaded, adding the script tag you suggest caused the process to fail. Maybe geometry is included with the drawing library? Works for me. (And as Leonardo said, lose the 'new' in front of the static method.)

Comment: Thanks, I spent a lot of time scratching my head when I ran into this. In my case it was triggering the jquery load event before the this part of the library was loaded.

Comment: And if you're requiring more than one library, just comma-separate them like this: `?libraries=geometry,visualization` ..etc.

Comment: Additional help for searchers where this may not be a complete solution: if you're loading the geometry library and using an API key, you **must** put the `libraries` parameter before the `key` parameter. I was stuck for ages on this point

Answer (score 6):

This is not working because you are using "new" for use the computeArea method.
Use "google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea" without "new".
Example:

```
var z = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(myPolyline.getPath().getArray());
alert(z);
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my below code

```
var z = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(poligon.getPath());
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, while this may answer the question, it is better to give explanations and not only code for your answer.