# Google Maps API v3 - google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation not working the first time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having the problem that google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latLng,polygon) does not work the first time when the page load, but it works later after I start to fire events.

Any idea of why this may be happening?

Thanks !

Comment: What error do you get in the JavaScript console?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: JavaScript console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'poly' of undefined

Comment: Sounds like the first time  you call it the API hasn't loaded yet.  But as you haven't provided any code, that is just a guess.

Comment: I found the source of the error ... I needed to specify "libraries=geometry" in the initial Google API call. See similar question at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765667/calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon). Thanks for the tips !

Answer (score 4):

Main reason is at first time google api is not loaded properly and you are trying to use

```
var rsul = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(-12.043333, -77.028333), bermudaTriangle);
```

so it is showing 'Cannot read property 'poly' of undefined'

so we need to use timeout to getting work on page load.

example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var rsul = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(-12.043333, -77.028333), bermudaTriangle);
    console.log(rsul);
}, 1000);
```

so it is giving proper boolean value

Comment: The correct answer is not to use a timeout, but to add a callback to be executed when the Script is loaded in the page.

Comment: @Juan Are you thinking about the callback on loading the main Google Maps JavaScript library? Right now I am seeing this problem though I am using the callback. And I have added `&libraries=geometry`. There is a bug in v3 I think.